# How to make Twitter API requests to statuses/user_timeline

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have created a Twitter Developer account and would like to use it to monitor tweets. As such, I will be using [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline). I have created an app on https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps, and I can view consumer API keys as well as access token / access token secret. However, after reading through the Twitter docs for quite some time I just can't figure out how to authenticate myself. I figured I needed to pass some HTTP headers or something, but I'm not sure. Here is my code at the moment:

```
import requests


def main():
    request_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
    parameters = {
        "screen_name": "jack",
        "count": 3,
        "exclude_replies": True,
        "include_rts": False
    }
    r = requests.get(request_url, params=parameters)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: To avoid having to handle the complex authentication stuff, why not use an existing Python library like python-twitter or tweepy or twython?

Comment: @AndyPiper I don't see why I should need a package other than requests for something so simple?

Comment: That's a fair point, but I don't think requests supports OAuth directly without using requests_oauthlib functions. Take a look at the Python sample in the Twitter docs https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweets-and-users/quick-starts/get-users. If you want something that needs less lines of code, you could try a library that wraps that for you.